# Visual Studio 2010 "cannot find" C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Temp\1\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.vb after every reboot

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I recently added some of my Visual Studio 2010 projects to a solution, and now every time I reopen the program they stop compiling.  They complain "Unable to open module file C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Temp\1.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.vb.  System cannot find the file specified."  I've checked, the file exists and is accessible from the VS Editor itself!

All the information about this error I've found recommends using rebuild to work around the issue.  That works for me, but I would rather not have to run a rebuild the first time I open every one of my solutions!  Is there someway to avoid this error?

Comment: The \1\ looks like a remote desktop Session ID. When you log off, the Session is removed.

Comment: It is a little helper file that the IDE generates to help the IntelliSense parser figure out what target framework was selected.  This is an environmental problem, hard to guess what's wrong with your machine.  You'd better check out what is all getting started up automatically when you reboot.  Use SysInternals' AutoRuns

Comment: @vcsjones, I am accessing the development box via RDC, so you probably have the problem right.  Is there a way to avoid this file being created/needed when in a Remote environment?  Or to recreate it automatically on logon?

Comment: I get this and I don't use RDC (my path stops at \Temp), any other suggestions as to what causes it?

Comment: @BlackICE: The problem occurs because Visual Studio generates it when you build, and Visual Studio assumes that if a .suo file exists for your solution, then that file must also exist.  Anything that cleans up the TEMP folder can delete that file, and cause the problem.  RDC makes this much more visible because it happens to create/delete a TEMP directory on login.

Comment: Very good response.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Yes, this is a problem caused by Remote Desktop Connections.  RDC is (by default) setup to use create a new directory each time you log in remotely.  Also, it's setup (separate setting) to delete that directory once you log off.  The real solution is to remove these two settings so that it will just use your standard Temp folder, not deleting the files at logout.

There are also two workarounds to this problem:

1. Workaround 1: Delete your .suo file for the solution before opening the solution or rebuilding.
2. Workaround 2: Use the "Rebuild All" option for the fix

<sub>Note: Setting up RDC can really only be done if you're logged on as an administrator on the box, thus, the two workarounds.</sub>

Comment: Where are these settings located?

Comment: @just.another.programmer [Configure Temporary Folders for an RD Session Host Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755098).  (In case the link dies) They're in the control panel: Administrative Tools > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration

Comment: Not necessarily caused by RDP, but that is the most common, and is recognizable by the \1\ in the path. In my case, my Temp directory was emptied last week by the Windows 10 update to build 15063. Disk cleanup can do it too, if you put a check mark at 'Temporary Files'. And I guess I don't need to tell you to steer clear of those system cleaners and optimizers certain web sites spam you about.

Comment: The .suo file will be saved in the folder where your Solution (.sln) file exists. You might wanted to set true for “Show Hidden Files and Folder” in “Folder Options” as .suo file is default by hidden.

C:\~\Solution.sln\.vs\SolutionName\v14

Comment: I'm using VS2017: deleting the .vs folder did it for me. It may be that deleting just the .suo file in that tree would be more precise.

Comment: Workaround 1 worked with my website projects and VS.NET 2013.

Comment: Deleting .SUO did not work until I closed all instances of Visual Studio, after that and rebuilding was all good

Answer (score 6):

I restarted visual studio and that did the trick...

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug in the Visual Studio 2010. Clean and build works for me.

Comment: Not just vs 2010.  Same issue in 2015

Answer (score 3):

In my case VS couldn't access to users TEMP folder. After changing permissions to allow all users (my computer has one user - me) full control over this folder, everything was fixed.

Hope this will help.

Comment: This was the problem I had, C# solution not VB but same deal.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to create the desired files at the desired location. That would be:

**"C:\Users\user\appdata\local\temp\1.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client.AssemblyAttributes.cs"** with the following content:

```
// <autogenerated />
using System;
using System.Reflection;
[assembly: global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute(".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile")]
```

**"C:\Users\user\appdata\local\temp\1.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs"** with the following content:

```
// <autogenerated />
using System;
using System.Reflection;
[assembly: global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute(".NETFramework,Version=v4.0", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4")]
```

**"C:\Users\user\appdata\local\temp\1.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.vb"** with the following content:

```
Option Strict Off
        Option Explicit On

        Imports System
        Imports System.Reflection
        <Assembly: Global.System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute(".NETFramework,Version=v4.0", FrameworkDisplayName:=".NET Framework 4")>
```

for other version of .NET, just change the version in the file contents e.g.

```
[assembly: global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute(".NETFramework,Version=v4.5", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4.5")]
```

Comment: The error message might disappear, but I encountered other strange problems, i.e. Visual Studio 2015 did not change my settings for debug output filtering which was pretty annoying, after configuring tempory folders the problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the AssemblyAttributes.vb file and it magically got recereated. that's how I solved.

Comment: This works for me. Not sure how but after delete, I've clean and rebuild and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Do not open the solution directly from the visual studio 2010. open the solution by clicking the project solution file from the folder where the project has been saved.

its resolved my problem...

Comment: I wonder what about that would solve the problem described here.

Answer (score 0):

Like vcsjones said, it looks like a problem with RDC.  It fixed itself after I closed my RDC session and reset the terminal server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your drive have enough free space.
I have experienced the same issue, resolved after allocating more free space in the drive