# Could not find file 'C:\Users\crims\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ProjectAssemblies\...\MonitoringSystemDatabase.mdb'

Tags: database, ms-access, vb.net-2010

I have a Menu Form and it has 7 UserControls every time I execute my program I keep seeing this error.

[image: Main Menu Error]

I have no idea what error is this. I tried searching but there are no error close related to mine. Then I compare my error with this [Project Assemblies error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6318085/7625175)

Can anyone help me with this? I have no idea what causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by your code looking for the MS Access database file called:

```
MonitoringSystemDatabase.mdb
```

...is located at path:

```
C:\Users\crims\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ProjectAssemblies\cjz5kapb01\
```

...but it is not.

Locate file `MonitoringSystemDatabase.mdb` (perhaps with <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> +<kbd>E</kbd> to Search), note the actual path of the file, and correct the path in `MainMenu.vb`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear, so why all the searching?

Either the file isn't there, or the application can't see it where it expects to find it.

Try moving the file to:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\MonitoringSystemDatabase.mdb
```

and adjust you project accordingly.